# DropList field in WFFM is showing value in message body

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers

we have identified an issue/functional requirement that we have a droplist of countries and same goes for title like in below image

[image]

but we need that in response email body of send email save action it's Arabic text should be used instead of English value of selected option. Is there a solution or fix ? or we have to go for any customization ?

Comment: what version of sitecore and wffm do you have? are you using WFFM Mvc?

Comment: Sitecore CMS 
7.2 rev. 140228 (Initial Release)

Web Forms for Marketers
2.4 rev.141008

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way out-of-the-box to use the text instead of value. What you can do is create a custom "Send Email Message", similar to Sitecore.Form.Submit.SendMail and override the FormatMail method.

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of countries items somewhere in the Sitecore Content Tree, and add a field for the text/description of the country. Then in WFFM droplist field, `Set Items by: Selecting Sitecore Items` and `Select Root Item` to the folder of the list of countries you created earlier.

You should see the countries in the preview section. Click the drop arrow for the Value and Text fields and then either select `Display name` or the custom field in your country item that holds the translated values.

The value submitted in form will now be the translated value correct for the language, using the lookup items list.

[image: WFFM Country List]

[image: WFFM List Items]

Comment: Thanks for an idea but when i am selecting field value for both text and value for droplist, In email message body and response report we are not getting any value in arabic culture and everything is working as expected in english(default) culture.
Below screencast for reference:
http://screencast.com/t/8mrSQEGC
http://screencast.com/t/DqWpMUd5WE
http://screencast.com/t/jhLcRanmAN

Comment: Check the values in the HTML select field is rendered correctly in Arabic (the `value` attribute, not just the displayed text). If it is then it's a bug in WFFM and you should raise it with Sitecore Support.

Comment: You are right it's rendered correctly (http://screencast.com/t/CHB19GNjsF) I have raised a support ticket as well.
Thanks